# Compiling error invalid operands to binary && (have 'int' and 'pthread_t' {aka 'struct <anonymous>'})

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile some C code and I get this error

error: invalid operands to binary && (have 'int' and 'pthread_t' {aka 'struct "<"anonymous>'})

the code in question is

```
static void kill_mining(void)
{
    struct thr_info *thr;
    int i;

    forcelog(LOG_DEBUG, "Killing off mining threads");
    /* Kill the mining threads*/
    for (i = 0; i < mining_threads; i++) {
        pthread_t *pth = NULL;

        thr = get_thread(i);
        if (thr && PTH(thr) != 0L)
            pth = &thr->pth;
        thr_info_cancel(thr);
        if (pth && *pth)   <---- This is where it goes wrong
            pthread_join(*pth, NULL);
    }
}
```

I don't know C so I'm a bit lost on how to fix this. Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks

Edit: Code comes from https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer and its the cgminer.c file.

Comment: `pthread_t` is an anonymous structure. So you cannot dereference pointers to it.

Comment: Where did you get this code from?

Comment: If you want further help then you need to provide complete code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Possibly you just need to make `pth` a `pthread_t` and not a `pthread_t *`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I have edited the thread and included the code source.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
pthread_t *pth;
```

dereferencing the `pth` value with

```
if (pth && *pth)
```

is wrong.

`pthread_t` is [defined under POSIX in `sys/types.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html):

> The <sys/types.h> header shall define at least the following types:
>
> ```
>  .
>  .
>  .
> pthread_t
>     Used to identify a thread.
>  .
>  .
>  .
> ```

with the added caveat

> All of the types shall be defined as arithmetic types of an appropriate length, with the following exceptions:
>
> ```
>  .
>  .
>  .
> pthread_t
>  .
>  .
>  .
> ```

It is improper and wrong to treat a `pthread_t` variable as an object that can be evaluated as part of a boolean expression.